# Force:recordView - Not seeing the Case record in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I am trying to dispay my case record on app but i am not seeing anything on my app. can someone please help.

```
<aura:component controller="openCaseController" >
<aura:attribute name="cases" type="case[]" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:iteration items="{!v.cases}" var="case">
    <div>
        <force:recordView recordId="{!case.Id}" type="MINI"/>   
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) 
{
    var action = component.get("c.getCaseDB");
    console.log("Calling doInit");
    action.setCallback(this,function(response)
                       {
                           var state=response.getState();
                           if (state==="SUCCESS" )
                           {
                               console.log("Getting case");
                               component.set("v.cases",response.getReturnValue());
                               console.log(response.getReturnValue());

                           }
                       });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);

   }
})
```

Class:

```
public class openCaseController 
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getCaseDB()
    {
        return [select id,status,Description,CaseNumber from case where status='Closed' limit 10];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "type=MINI" is not a supported attribute and the documentation will be updated to reflect this. The only supported type for force:recordView is "FULL" in which you do not need to specify it.

Salesforce encourages developers to move away from force: namespaced components in favor of lightning: namespaced components (such as lightning:recordViewForm, lightning:recordEditForm, and lightning:recordViewForm) where possible. So you can use [lightning:recordViewForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_recordViewForm.htm)

```
<aura:component controller="openCaseController" >
    <aura:attribute name="cases" type="case[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.cases}" var="case">
        <div>
            <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!case.Id}" objectApiName="Case">
                <div class="slds-box">

                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="CaseNumber" />
                </div>
            </lightning:recordViewForm>
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

ref: [Known issue 1](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ewvsQAA&title=components-using-force-recordview-type-mini-do-not-display-correctly-in-lightning-experience) and [Known issue 2](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018B6kQAE)

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. This solution worked.  Do i need to add every field that i want to show on my page ? Is there a way i can show complete record ?

Comment: yes you can do that.

Comment: Can you please tell me how we can do it ?

Comment: Do you see output field in above code which defines field name? Similar way add other fields

Comment: I was trying to say is there any one line markup to show all details like we have force:recordView which display all fields when we use type="MINI"?

Comment: no there is no way to that. You need to add every field individually